# Regexp_Replace for special values

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

My Regexp_replace query `(AIM,'-<\w*>$','')`  doesn't help me to remove `-<SLOT>` from my values.

Original Values `SAC-1-0-3-<SLOT>`

Desired Value `SAC-1-0-3`

Comment: Actually, [your query seems to be working fine for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9fd4402957d0aa5d9471df862b49b169), assuming the query in the demo is what you are actually running.

Comment: Show few more examples of your data and let us know what's not working.